# Unable to create a file in a folder present inside Workspace

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create a script that will convert Dictionary data to str data using JSON_DUMP. And that will get written in a .txt file under Workspace/Users/test@gmail.com/Result path . The query is running successfully but no file is getting created in the path.

```
with open("file:\\Workspace\\Users\\test@gmail.com\\RESULT\\convert.txt",'w') as convert_file:
  json.dump(Final_result,convert_file)
```

How should I modify my query?

I tried the following command and it is showing the file is already existing.

`open('file:\\Workspace\\Users\\test@gmail.com\\RESULT\\convert.txt',"x")`

So how can I view the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Databricks:

```py
file_path = "file:/dbfs/Workspace/Users/test@gmail.com/RESULT/convert.txt"
dbutils.fs.put(file_path, json.dumps(Final_result), True)
dbutils.fs.head(file_path)
```

And, check [Databricks Utilities (`dbutils`) reference](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html) for more on how to work with Databricks File System (DBFS) using `dbutils`.

Also, I suppose you were trying to access the files from UI? (please correct me if I am wrong). If yes, then you'll have to:

- First [save the file to
  `/Filestore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/filestore#save-a-file-to-filestore), and
- Your Databricks admin must enable the [dbfs-browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace-settings/dbfs-browser) (ignore if already enabled)
- Then, you can click on "Catalog" in the sidebar, then "DBFS" and now you can access your files saved in the `/Filestore` from UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try `open('file:\\Workspace\\Users\\test@gmail.com\\RESULT\\convert.txt',"r")`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

```
'x' open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
```